# How to share sign in with apple on more than 5 apps?

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, apple-sign-in

When trying to add sign in with apple to meet app store requirements, I hit a roadblock.

After trying to follow [this guide on apple sign in](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple), **it seems only 5 apps can be linked for apple sign in.**

My use case has more than 5 apps on the app store.
Let's say we have 26 apps, `A...Z`

**Here is the desired behavior:**

1. Someone signs in with apple on `App A`.
2. I verify that token on my API, and create a user for them, and associate with that apple token in some way.
3. The same person signs in with apple on `App B`
4. I verify the token on my API, and can tell that they are the same user from steps 1 and 2
5. This process works for any of my apps `A...Z`.

Apple's settings for configuring an apple sign in key only allow up to 5 apps to be in a group. From my understanding, this would prevent my use case from working with more than 5 apps.

I have had a hard time finding anyone talking about grouping apps when configuring apple sign in.

**How can I get more than 5 apps to work as described?**

Comment: You currently can't. You could submit an enhancement request to Apple.